Removing the title of MKV files with JMkvpropedit
I am trying to remove the title of a batch of MKV files with JMkvpropedit, because I want VLC to display the "Windows" name of the file at the beginning of the video instead of the eventual "metadata" title (which VLC does if this title doesn't exist).
Unfortunately, I cannot do this, and nothing is displayed instead of the "Windows" name.
Process:

I add the file(s) in the "Input" tab of JMkvpropedit.
I tick the "Title" box in the "General" tab, and put nothing in the input field.
I press the "Process files" button.

If I remove the "metadata" title with MKVToolnix-GUI, the "Windows" name is displayed as intended, but I have hundreds of files and I don't want to do every one separately.

MKVToolNix comes with mkvpropedit, which could probably do this. It could then be batch-applied using shell scripting.

@DanielB  JMkvpropedit is actually a GUI for mkvpropedit, and I tried some sripts for shell, but I'm not very confortable with it...

@DanielB However, if you had a script I could use in PowerShell or cmd that would work for folders and subfolders, I'd gladly try it.

Use {file_name} as the title.
From the Mac version…


Thank you @Tetsujin, I am a bit ashamed because it is literaly written under the input field. I just tried it and it doesn't seem to work for me, but I'll look deeper into this tonight.

Sorry for the late reply, but I got bored after many unsuccessful attempts and gave up, then tried again and got better results. The {file_name} method seems to work, but only I generate a command line and paste it into cmd (it gives me errors with PowerShell admin). I managed to fix all the files in a short time, although it's probably not the best method. Thanks again for the help.

By using mkvpropedit directly, you can delete the title from a single file like this:
mkvpropedit my-video.mkv --edit info --delete title

This just leaves the problem of batch editing multiple files. This is a task that is typically done using the shell. Using PowerShell, you could do it like this:
$mkvs = Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.mkv" -Recurse
# Optionally verify the files found by entering just $mkvs
$mkvs | ForEach-Object { mkvpropedit.exe $_.FullName --edit info --delete title }

This will find all .mkv files in the current folder and its subfolders and will remove the title from all of them. If you don’t have mkvpropedit in $env:PATH, you’ll have to use its full path. If it’s in the current folder, that would be .\mkvpropedit.exe.
